# Swift 2 - Change buttons Background/Lock-Screen MediaPlayer

Tags: ios, audio, mpnowplayinginfocenter

In my app I have enabled the background audio in order for the user to play,pause, skip tracks from lock-screen.

Everything works however, I cannot find the way to show the `next track` and `previous track` buttons.

Right Now the `MediaPlayer' is showing different buttons(see image Attached)

[image]

in my `AppDelegate.swift` I have:

```
override func remoteControlReceivedWithEvent(event: UIEvent?) {
        if event!.type == UIEventType.RemoteControl {
            if event!.subtype == UIEventSubtype.RemoteControlPlay {
                print("received remote play")

            } else if event!.subtype == UIEventSubtype.RemoteControlPause {
                print("received remote pause")

            } else if event!.subtype == UIEventSubtype.RemoteControlTogglePlayPause {
                print("received toggle")

            }else if event!.subtype == UIEventSubtype.RemoteControlNextTrack{
                print("received next")

            }
        }
```

How can I change the buttons in order to show next and previous buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference it can be done using:

Swift 2:

```
        MPRemoteCommandCenter.sharedCommandCenter().skipBackwardCommand.enabled = false
        MPRemoteCommandCenter.sharedCommandCenter().seekBackwardCommand.enabled = false
        MPRemoteCommandCenter.sharedCommandCenter().skipForwardCommand.enabled = false
        MPRemoteCommandCenter.sharedCommandCenter().seekForwardCommand.enabled = false
```